# Firebase Firestore onSnapshot() doesn't react to changes in a subcollection

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, expo

I'm currently working on a react-native app with expo that uses firebase firestore as a database. In order to implement a chatting feature where users can have 1 on 1 conversations with other users, I've set up onSnapshot listeners in the code below that runs on app start. Essentially, what it should be doing is creating a listener for conversations that involve the user, and for each of those conversations, adds another listener for its 'messages' subcollection.

```
 const newListener = (convoRef.where("pIds", "array-contains", u.uid)
              .onSnapshot(convSnap => {
                convos = new Map();
                convSnap.forEach((conv) => {
                  if (!(conv.get("toDelete") == true)) {
                    convos.set(conv.id, conv)
                    const textsRef = firebase.firestore().collection('Conversations').doc(conv.id).collection('messages')
                    const newConvoListener = (textsRef
                      .orderBy('timestamp','desc')
                      .onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
                        //processes the new messages. omitted for brevity
                      }, err => {"Error fetching messages" + err}))
                      activeListeners.push(newConvoListener);
                  }
                })
              }, error => console.log("problem fetching conversation snapshot: " + error)
              ))
            activeListeners.push(newListener);
```

Elsewhere in the app, users can start conversations with others, which is done with this code. It essentially creates a new document representing a new conversation between the two users, then creates another document within the 'messages' subcollection of the aforementioned document that acts as a dummy message representing the start of their conversation.

```
await db.collection('Conversations').add({
      pIds: [uid,potentialMatchID],
      pNames: [username,potentialMatchName],
      pPics: [uPic ? uPic : null, potentialMatchPic ? potentialMatchPic : null],
      toDelete: false,
    }).catch((error) => {console.log("problem " + error + "\n" + pIds + pNames + pPics)})
    .then((newConversation) => {
       db.collection('Conversations').doc(newConversation.id).collection('messages').add({
        recipient: potentialMatchID,
        liked: false,
        text: uid,
        placeholder: true,
        timestamp: new firebase.firestore.Timestamp.now()
      });
    }).catch((error) => {console.log("problem adding conversation" + error)});
```

The issue I am having occurs when a new conversation is created between two users. Let's call the user that initiated the creation of the conversation (by running the code above) device A, while the receiving user is device B.

For device A, the conversations listener reacts to the change as expected, and creates a listener for the newly created conversation's 'messages' subcollection.

That subcollection listener <strike>correctly gets the dummy message during the initial fetch when the listener is being created, but then</strike> does not react to any <strike>further</strike> messages within the new conversation. New documents within the 'messages' subcollection do not cause the listener to activate, whether they be sent from device B or device A (they are still able to add new messages to the subcollection, but the listener never notices that they do so - the changes are only reflected in the console and on device B) or directly added to the subcollection via the console. The app has to be restarted for the listeners to start reacting appropriately to changes in firestore.

The listeners on device B all work perfectly. Their listeners correctly identify the new conversation, create a 'messages' listener, receive the initial dummy message, and then correctly react to new incoming/outgoing messages. Similarly, the conversations that were already there for device A continue to behave normally, and if a third device starts a conversation with device A, device A responds appropriately.

So, I'm pretty sure the issue has to do with the fact that device A is creating a listener for a collection that they themselves created just moments ago. I think it *might* have something to do with local writes being registered by listeners instantly before they go out to firestore, but not sure.

On the firebase end, it's set up like this:

Conversations Collection -> individual documents representing a conversation and its metadata -> Messages Subcollection -> individual documents representing a message within the parent conversation

Comment: Please try to reduce the scope of the question as having too much unnecessary code adds difficulty to finding the root issue. Simplifying the question to a [minimal reproducible sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).